# Using Windows 7 Pro x64 Retail Upgrade To Upgrade A Windows 7 Pro x32 OEM Install

Tags: windows-7, licensing

I have two Dell computers that came with Windows 7 Pro 32-bit edition (with OEM licensing).

Can I upgrade them to the 64-bit edition using a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit retail *Upgrade* disk?

Is their a cheaper way to do this (I.e. can I just call dell and get them to send me a link to a Windows 7 x64 Pro `.iso` with OEM licensing)?

Comment: Looks like I answered my own question.  Per a dell service rep, the OEM license does cover both 32 bit and x64 editions.  He said to just use the Windows 7 Pro x64 disk I had from another Dell computer to install on the 32 bit machines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Comment: Note that you can't upgrade from x86 to x64 regardless - it requires a clean install.  The Dell disk should handle it fine, though.

Comment: Borrow a Dell branded W7 Pro 64bit install disc from a friend, neighbor, clasmate, or co-worker, this is the cheapest way.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, the key doesn't matter when it comes to x86 vs x64, only version like Home Professional, Pro, Ultimate.